# On Update, change date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, datetime, insert

I am using SqlServer 2005. I would like to set a property (like default value, but for any change, not just inserts) that would update a date. In other words, on every update and insert, the current date would be placed in the column. How would this be achieved?

Comment: A date in each row, or one single date somewhere?

Comment: You're probably looking for an [INSTEAD OF TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799(v=sql.90).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you have an `A` table:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  ID INT,
  Name VARCHAR(20),
  SomeDate DATE NULL)
```

You can create triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER INSTEAD_OF_A_INSERT
ON A
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO A (ID, Name, SomeDate)
SELECT ID, Name, GETDATE ()
FROM inserted 

END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER INSTEAD_OF_A_UPDATE
ON A
INSTEAD OF UPDATE AS
BEGIN

UPDATE A
SET SomeDate = GETDATE(),
    Name = I.Name
FROM A A1 JOIN INSERTED I ON A1.ID = I.ID

END
GO
```

Which will give what you want

```
INSERT INTO A (ID, Name)
VALUES(1, 'John');

INSERT INTO A (ID, Name)
VALUES(2, 'Jack');

UPDATE A
SET Name = 'Jane'

    SELECT *
    FROM A
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ac20/1) you can play with.

Comment: Thanks. I've read a little on triggers. Is this the only way to do it, other than just updates/inserting the value directly? I'm trying to find my best options, although it does seem that triggers is the standard.

Comment: If you want to do it at DB server level this is the only way I know of.

Comment: @steventnorris if you can control data access via stored procedures, then you wouldn't *necessarily* need a trigger if you set permissions correctly and control those who can bypass the procedures. But if you allow ad hoc DML then yes this is the way I would do it (while you consider whether you should allow ad hoc DML).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (but not necessarily most efficient) way to do this would be with a trigger.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).

You could either use an `AFTER INSERT,UPDATE` or an `INSTEAD OF INSERT,UPDATE` - either could be made to do the job depending on your exact requirements.